# How to handle checkboxes in a listview and send information back from a custom base adapter

Tags: java, android

I have a list view and each item contains a check box and other various text views. In the Main Activity I have an ArrayList of objects called listOfStuff. From the main activity I'm defining and using a custom base adapter. In the getView method I defined a listener for the check box like so:

```
holder.cbCompletionStatus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(holder.cbCompletionStatus.isChecked()){
            listOfStuff.get(position).setComplete(1);
        } else {
            listOfStuff.get(position).setComplete(0);
        };
    }
});
```

My problem is that I don't know how to access the listOfStuff and the objects within it to modify the information within. The code in the if/else statement hopefully gives an idea what I was trying to do. Just a quick warning, I'm not only new to Android and Java, but to programming field on the whole. Thanks.

UPDATE:
So I ended up figuring this out on my own. I just had to make the listOfStuff Arraylist a static in the Main Activity. Then I could call a static function in the Main Activity to manipulate whatever data in the Array list I needed like so:

MainActivity.checkBoxClicked(result, position);

Comment: So I ended up figuring this out on my own.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my class:

```
class ImageInfoAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if(viewcount == 0){
            return 0;
        }
        return viewcount;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return isSentAlList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder viewHolder;
        View rowView=view;

        if(rowView==null){
            LayoutInflater layoutinflate =  LayoutInflater.from(ListPictures.this);
            rowView=layoutinflate.inflate(R.layout.listviewayout, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            viewHolder.textViewisSentFlag = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.textViewisSentFlag);
            viewHolder.imageViewToSent = (ImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewToSent);
            viewHolder.checkBoxToSend = (CheckBox)rowView.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxToSend);

            rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else{
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.ref = position;
        Log.i("InfoLog","viewHolder.ref = position; "+viewHolder.ref); 
        viewHolder.textViewisSentFlag.setText(isSentAlList.get(position)); 
        Bitmap blob = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAlList.get(position), 0, imageAlList.get(position).length);
        viewHolder.imageViewToSent.setImageBitmap(blob);
        viewHolder.checkBoxToSend.setClickable(true);

        if(checked.containsKey(""+viewHolder.ref)){   ///if this id is present as key in hashmap  
            Log.i("InfoLog","checked.containsKey "+viewHolder.ref);
            if(checked.get(""+viewHolder.ref).equals("true")){  //also check whether it is true or false to check/uncheck checkbox 
                Log.i("InfoLog","checked.get(position) "+viewHolder.ref); 
                viewHolder.checkBoxToSend.setChecked(true);
            } else
                viewHolder.checkBoxToSend.setChecked(false);
        } else
            viewHolder.checkBoxToSend.setChecked(false);

        viewHolder.checkBoxToSend.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OncheckchangeListner(viewHolder));
        return rowView;

    }//End of method getView
}//End of class ImageInfo



class ViewHolder{

    private TextView textViewisSentFlag = null;
    private ImageView imageViewToSent = null;
    private CheckBox checkBoxToSend = null;

    int ref;
}//End of class ViewHolder
```

/////////////////////////
and here is my oncheckchangedlistener
////////////////////////

```
class OncheckchangeListner implements OnCheckedChangeListener{
    ViewHolder viewHolder = null; 
    public OncheckchangeListner(ViewHolder viHolder) {
        viewHolder =  viHolder;  
    }
    @Override 
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
            boolean isChecked) {
        if(viewHolder.checkBoxToSend.equals(buttonView)) {       
            if(!isChecked) {
                Log.i("InfoLog","checked.get before "+checked.get(""+viewHolder.ref));
                checked.put(""+viewHolder.ref,"false");
                Log.i("InfoLog","checked.get after "+checked.get(""+viewHolder.ref));
            } else
                checked.put(""+viewHolder.ref,"true");
        } else
            Log.i("InfoLog","i m in checkchange ");
    }
}
```